# R bind_rows not behaving consistently when using %>%

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following tibble

```
tst <- tibble(
  x = 'actual data',
  age_1 = 5.3,
  age_2 = 6.6,
  age_3 = 8.3,
  age_4 = 20.3,
  age_5 = 25.3,
  age_6 = 30.8,
  age_7 = 31.3,
  age_8 = 22.3,
  age_9 = 18.3,
  age_10 = 14.3
)
```

I am able to create a new row of the rounded first row values with

```
demo <- tst %>% 
  c(x='round',round(.[nrow(.),2:(ncol(.))])) %>% 
  bind_rows(tst,.)

demo
# A tibble: 2 x 11
  x           age_1 age_2 age_3 age_4 age_5 age_6 age_7 age_8 age_9 age_10
  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 actual data  5.30  6.60  8.30  20.3  25.3  30.8  31.3  22.3  18.3   14.3
2 round        5.00  7.00  8.00  20.0  25.0  31.0  31.0  22.0  18.0   14.0
```

Now when I try and create another row of the floor values using the same code, I get an error

```
demo %>%
  c(x='floor',round(demo[1,2:(ncol(demo))])) %>% 
  bind_rows(demo,.)
Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 12 must be length 2, not 1
```

However, if I do what I think is the same thing in a more round about way, it works

```
i <- c(x='floor',round(demo[1,2:(ncol(demo))]))
bind_rows(demo,i)
# A tibble: 3 x 11
  x           age_1 age_2 age_3 age_4 age_5 age_6 age_7 age_8 age_9 age_10
  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 actual data  5.30  6.60  8.30  20.3  25.3  30.8  31.3  22.3  18.3   14.3
2 round        5.00  7.00  8.00  20.0  25.0  31.0  31.0  22.0  18.0   14.0
3 floor        5.00  7.00  8.00  20.0  25.0  31.0  31.0  22.0  18.0   14.0
```

I have no idea why I get that error when running what is essentially the same code as when I created the rounded row. Any ideas? If you have suggestions of a better way to do this (adding rows based on the rows above it) I would love to hear them.

Comment: I'm curious why you aren't using `tibble::add_row`, your approach seems quite unsual. If you replace `c()` with `data.frame()` or `tibble` that would seem more natural.

Comment: so just use add_row from the get go. How do I automatically add each cell for each column, i.e., add_row(tst,x='round',round(tst[1,2:(ncol(tst))]))? I don;t want to have to do it individually for each row (age_1, age_2, etc)

Comment: To be honest, you should be working in long format, not wide... I can put it as an answer to illustrate

Comment: that would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with wide datasets can be very counter-intuitive in R. It is almost always preferable to work with your data in long format. Right up to the point where you may want to display in a wide table for example.

I would reshape your data similar to this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

tst <- tibble(
  x = 'actual data',
  age_1 = 5.3,
  age_2 = 6.6,
  age_3 = 8.3,
  age_4 = 20.3,
  age_5 = 25.3,
  age_6 = 30.8,
  age_7 = 31.3,
  age_8 = 22.3,
  age_9 = 18.3,
  age_10 = 14.3
)

df <- tst %>%
  select(-x) %>%
  gather(var, actual) %>%
  mutate(
    var = "age",
    round = round(actual),
    floor = floor(actual)
  )

df
# # A tibble: 10 x 4
#  var   actual round floor
#  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 age   5.30  5.00  5.00
#  2 age   6.60  7.00  6.00
#  3 age   8.30  8.00  8.00
#  4 age  20.3  20.0  20.0 
#  5 age  25.3  25.0  25.0 
#  6 age  30.8  31.0  30.0 
#  7 age  31.3  31.0  31.0 
#  8 age  22.3  22.0  22.0 
#  9 age  18.3  18.0  18.0 
# 10 age  14.3  14.0  14.0
```

You can now see how easily your `round` and `floor` were added. To display quickly in wide format from the console, you can transpose it to the representation from your original question.

```
df %>% select(-var) %>% t

#        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# actual  5.3  6.6  8.3 20.3 25.3 30.8 31.3 22.3 18.3  14.3
# round   5.0  7.0  8.0 20.0 25.0 31.0 31.0 22.0 18.0  14.0
# floor   5.0  6.0  8.0 20.0 25.0 30.0 31.0 22.0 18.0  14.0
```

A `tidy` approach, instead of the quick look may be to:

```
df %>%
  mutate(cols = paste(var, sprintf("%02d", seq_len(nrow(.))), sep = "_")) %>%
  gather(var, value, -cols) %>%
  filter(var != "var") %>%
  spread(cols, value) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(2:length(.)), as.numeric)

# # A tibble: 3 x 11
#   var    age_01 age_02 age_03 age_04 age_05 age_06 age_07 age_08 age_09 age_10
#   <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 actual   5.30   6.60   8.30   20.3   25.3   30.8   31.3   22.3   18.3   14.3
# 2 floor    5.00   6.00   8.00   20.0   25.0   30.0   31.0   22.0   18.0   14.0
# 3 round    5.00   7.00   8.00   20.0   25.0   31.0   31.0   22.0   18.0   14.0
```

> **N.B.** In this variant, I added the `mutate_at` because the numeric values were coerced to character by the `gather` of mixed types.

Comment: @brownshoes, my pleasure, enjoy